# Multiple incrementing conditional clauses in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called raw_df. 
I want the rows in which the first column have `E01`, `E02`, ... `E14`.
How can I write a list comprehension (or another way) that can produce this, without typing it out manually.

```
row_data = raw_df.loc[
              (raw_df.col0=='E01') | (raw_df.col0=='E02') | 
              (raw_df.col0=='E03') | (raw_df.col0=='E04') | 
              (raw_df.col0=='E05') | (raw_df.col0=='E06') | 
              (raw_df.col0=='E07') | (raw_df.col0=='E08') | 
              (raw_df.col0=='E09') | (raw_df.col0=='E10') |
              (raw_df.col0=='E11') | (raw_df.col0=='E12') | 
              (raw_df.col0=='E13') | (raw_df.col0=='E14') 
              ]
```

I know it can be done with `eval` making a string list comprehension, but I understand that it's dangerous & should not be used.

Similarly, `setattr` only works for `xx.yy=z`, but not `xx.yy`**==**`z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) by `list` of all values generated by `Series` or by `list comprehension`s:

```
a = pd.Series(range(1, 15)).astype(str).str.zfill(2).radd('E')
row_data = raw_df.loc[raw_df.col0.isin(a)]
```

Detail:

```
print (a)
0     E01
1     E02
2     E03
3     E04
4     E05
5     E06
6     E07
7     E08
8     E09
9     E10
10    E11
11    E12
12    E13
13    E14
dtype: object
```

Alternative:

```
a = ['E{:02d}'.format(x) for x in range(1, 15)]
print (a)
['E01', 'E02', 'E03', 'E04', 'E05', 'E06', 'E07', 
 'E08', 'E09', 'E10', 'E11', 'E12', 'E13', 'E14']
```

Alternative2, thanks [KPLauritzen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940850/multiple-incrementing-conditional-clauses-in-pandas/47940883#comment82851103_47940883):

```
conditions = [f'E{x:02}' for x in range(1, 15)]
```

Comment: And even construct the list as `conditions = [f'E{x:02}' for x in range(1, 15)]`

Comment: Thank you, added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you could also use a regexp:

```
filtered = a[a.str.contains('E*')]
```